# Expected Identifiers in Xcode? I need need help!

Tags: xcode, ios, macos

im using 3.2.6 iOS 4.3 to begins with. now the question i have is its telling me I have an (located on the "(@Implementation window, hvController;"):

Expected Identifier or '(' before '@' token

in the Delegate.m class

```
//HelloUniverseAppDelegate.M
(@Implementation window, hvController;
(...

//HelloUniverseAppDelegate.m
- (void)applicationDidFinishishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    HelloUniverseController *hvc = [[HelloUniverseController alloc]
                                    inWihhNibName:@"HelloUniverse" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self.hvController = hvc;

    [hvc release];

    [window addSubview:[self.hvController view]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible ;
    }

     - (Void)dealloc {
         [hvController release];
         [window release];
         [super dealloc];
     }

     HelloUniverseController *hvc = [HelloUniverseController alloc];
     hvc = [hvc initWithNibName:@"HelloUniverse" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

#import "HelloUniverseAppDelegate.h"

@implementation HelloUniverseAppDelegate

@synthesize window;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called as part of  transition from the background to the inactive state: here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Free up as much memory as possible by purging cached data objects that can be recreated (or reloaded from disk) later.
     */
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end



now also its telling me I have a similar error in the Controller.h with

Expected Identifier before '{' token

its located on the "- (void)dealloc :{" line. the code I have for it is

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface HelloUniverseController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *txtFirstName;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtLastName;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
}

- (IBAction) btnClickMe_Clicked:(id)sender;

//HelloUniverseController.m

- (void)dealloc :{
[txtFirstName release];
[txtLastName release];
[lblMessage release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

im also very new at this, my second day ever using a mactonish as well as first with Xcode.

Comment: Where do you have that code from? It is horrible.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C requires that classes have two parts: the interface, which usually appears in a .h file and declares the class' instance variables, properties, and methods; and the implementation, which should be in a .m file and defines the class' methods. You seem to be trying to define the `-dealloc` method inside an @interface block rather than inside an @implementation block, and that's leading to at least one of the errors you're getting.

Frankly, one cannot avoid the impression that you've copied and pasted code from somewhere without understanding very much about the language. There are a number of blatant errors that just don't make any sense, including the one I just described and the #import statement that seems to be part of your `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.

StackOverflow is a great community that will, I'm sure, be happy to help you as you learn to program. However, you'll quickly wear out your welcome if you haven't made an effort to learn the basic syntax of the language. More importantly, it's really not going to help you if we just keep correcting your errors. Please, please read [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html). Or, if you don't have any experience with C-based languages (C, C++, C#, Java...) and some form of object-oriented programming, consider picking up a third-party book aimed at beginners. Thanks to the huge popularity of iPhone and iPad, there are plenty of books to choose from.

Comment: Progreamming in Objective-C, 3rd Edition, by Kochan, looks like an excellent book to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this

```
(
```

before

```
(@implementation
```

Comment: Isn't this also case-sensitive (`@implementation`)?