# Expected Identifiers '(' before 'Synthesize"

Tags: xcode, ios, macos

What does the '(' mean?

And the code im having trouble with is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ZelNoteAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {        
   UIWindow *window;        
   UITextField *textfield;      
   UITextView *textview;        
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;    
(@synthesize, @dynamic UITextField *textfield;    
@synthesize, @dynamic UITextView *textview;    
@end
```

Comment: Why do you seem to have a habit of placing `(`s everywhere in your code where Apple doesn't say you need to place them?

Comment: ... and why do you want to synthesize those properties in the header?

Comment: Bolt & Carl are right - after reviewing your question history, it looks to me like you're just making stuff up and hoping the compiler figures it out. Programming doesn't work like that, I'm afraid - you actually need to read the docs and learn the language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expected Identifiers in Xcode? I need need help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752434/expected-identifiers-in-xcode-i-need-need-help)

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ZelNoteAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {        
   UIWindow *window;        
   UITextField *textfield;      
   UITextView *textview;        
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textfield;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textview;    
@end

@interface ZelNoteAppDelegate 
@synthesize window, textField, textView;
// ...
@end
```

It would help you to read again [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).